# MySQL only returning one value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Been trying to figure out what's wrong for nearly two hours now.

I have made a wall post feature for my website, posts should be displayed on the profile wall, however instead of all of the posts being displayed, only 1 is. I have no idea what is wrong with my code, I can't find any issues.

The $profile_username variable has been defined in previous code and works. Even if I just type the name of the profile in it still only returns one post.

```
//----------submit wall post----------//
$getwallposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wallposts` WHERE `postedto`='$profile_username' ORDER BY `postid`");

//check if any rows are returned
while($wallposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getwallposts)) {
    $postid = $wallposts['postid'];
    $postedby_username = $wallposts['postedby'];
    $wallpostdate = $wallposts['dateposted'];
    $wallpost = $wallposts['post'];

    $querypostedby_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$postedby_username'");

    //get the info above
    if (mysql_num_rows($querypostedby_info) > 0) {
        $getpostedby_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($querypostedby_info);

        $postedby_id = $getpostedby_info['id'];
        $postedby_profilepicture = $getpostedby_info['profilepicture'];
    }

    //lets keep the line breaks
    $wallpost=nl2br($wallpost);

    //display the posts
    $wallpoststicker = 
    "
    <div id='wallpost-container'>
        <div id='wallpost-header'>
            <img src='$postedby_profilepicture'><div id='wallpost-header-by'><a href='/profile.php?id=$postedby_id'>$postedby_username</a> said:</div>
            <div id='wallpost-date'>&bull; $wallpostdate</div> 
        </div>
        <div id='wallpost-content'>
            $wallpost
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
```

Also, I know that mysql is deprecated; my version of PHP can handle mysql queries fine though.

Comment: Hi again :)
What happens if you run `while($wallposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getwallposts)) { print_r($wallposts);}` ?

Comment: Array
(
    [postid] => 3
    [post] => lets test again
    [postedto] => Harry
    [postedby] => PLAYERBOMB
    [dateposted] => 14 Feb 2016
)
Array
(
    [postid] => 2
    [post] => Hey test here
    [postedto] => Harry
    [postedby] => PLAYERBOMB
    [dateposted] => 14 Feb 2016
)
Array
(
    [postid] => 1
    [post] => Hey this is a post.

Here is a new paragraph
    [postedto] => Harry
    [postedby] => PLAYERBOMB
    [dateposted] => 14 Feb 2016
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to do you echo you're output?
If it is after the While you will only get the last result that is stored in the variable.

Output within the while loop.

Comment: Ahh, it's echoed on a different file, I included this code file at the top of the file that it is echoed on, I'll sort that out one moment.

Comment: use 
    $wallpoststicker .= 

to append to variable string. then the problem is solved.
Declare $wallpoststicker = ""; before while.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues with that code. First, what it seems to be your problem:

```
$wallpoststicker = 
"
<div id='wallpost-container'>
    <div id='wallpost-header'>
        <img src='$postedby_profilepicture'><div id='wallpost-header-by'><a href='/profile.php?id=$postedby_id'>$postedby_username</a> said:</div>
        <div id='wallpost-date'>&bull; $wallpostdate</div> 
    </div>
    <div id='wallpost-content'>
        $wallpost
    </div>
</div>
";
```

This code overrides the $wallpoststicker variable on every loop. That's why you only print one result at the very end.

But secondly, you're doing a query within a loop, which is potentially very inefficient. Have you thought on doing a LEFT JOIN between "wallposts" and "users" so you have all the data you need before you start your loop?

Comment: @Harry Awesome!!! I have already loade your code into my IDE, http://dev.postbrain.com/harry.php

Comment: @Harry So, excuse me, is your MySQL issue solved completely now - or just the "$wallpoststicker"?

Comment: Sure, I'll email you one sec.